# What is "ui" parameter in hgnested.nclone()?

Tags: python, nested, mercurial, mercurial-extension

```
import hgnested

sour = "C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\mercurial\hgserver"

desti = "D:\Work"
hgnested.nclone(source = sour, dest = desti)
```

Here I am trying to clone a nested repository "hgserver" which has 5 more repositories in it. But I am getting and error,

```
TypeError: nclone() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

I then looked at the source code of hgnested package of python at this [link](https://bitbucket.org/cedk/hgnested/src/bd39764e6a83d3e85ce3d7c7da0e8fcccff4c926/hgnested/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) and found that the nclone() method takes an argument "ui" to which I don't understand what to pass.

```
def nclone(ui, source, dest=None, **opts):
```

Can anybody help me out.

PS:Due to my low reputation I am unable to add relevant tags for this question. Ex: hgnested, nclone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hgnested is not what you want if you wanted to clone a file from and to your local drive. As I read their "documentation", a few lines of nothing, it's just a small extension to Mercurial. If all you wanted to do is to *copy* a directory, you should do this:

```
import shutil 
shutil.copytree(sour, desti) # copy dirs 
# use shutil.copy() to copy files
```

And to answer your original question, ui is the user interface class from Mercurial.

> Here, ui and repo are the user interface and repository arguments
>   passed into an extension function as standard (see WritingExtensions
>   for more details). If you are not calling the Mercurial command
>   functions from an extension, you will need to create suitable ui and
>   repo objects yourself. The ui object can be instantiated from the ui
>   class in mercurial.ui; the repo object can either be a
>   localrepository, a httprepository, an sshrepository or a
>   statichttprepository (each defined in their own modules), though it
>   will most often be a localrepository.

Comment: yeah after a lot of digging I understood what ui is, your explanation sums up everything about my question. Thank you @abccd

Comment: can you say how to create a repo object. Thank you

Comment: You can follow [this guide](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/guide). In general, you can create a repo by typing `hg init foldername` in terminal

Answer (score 0):

```
import hgnested
from mercurial import ui
sour = "C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\mercurial\hgserver"

desti = "D:\Work"
hgnested.nclone(ui.ui(), source = sour, dest = desti)
```

as answered by @abccd, I just had to change my method call to above line and the clone was successful.